# Open Modal on node click

Tags: angular, vis.js

I'm trying to be able to open a modal when clicking on a node. More exactly, when clicking on a node, I would like to be able to trigger a function that would open a modal.

I manage to add an event during the click, I manage to open a modal from a function, but impossible to be able to link the two. I get this error when clicking:
**ERROR TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'open')**.

This is my code :

```
import { AfterViewInit, Component, ElementRef, Input, OnInit, ViewChild } from '@angular/core';
import { Network } from "vis-network";
import { DataSet } from "vis-data"
import { NgbActiveModal, NgbModal } from '@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap';
import { InformationsPageComponent } from '../informations-page/informations-page.component';


@Component({
  selector: 'app-vue-principale',
  templateUrl: './vue-principale.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./vue-principale.component.scss']
})

export class VuePrincipaleComponent implements AfterViewInit {
  public select: string = "30/01/01"

  networkInstance: any;
  @ViewChild('network') elem: ElementRef;
  constructor(public modalService: NgbModal) {}
  openView() {
    const modalRef = this.modalService.open(InformationsPageComponent);
  }
  ngAfterViewInit(): void {

    const container = this.elem.nativeElement;
    const nodes = new DataSet([
      { id: 1, label: 'Node 1', color: "blue", shape: 'diamond' },
      { id: 2, label: 'Node 2' },
      { id: 3, label: 'Node 3' },
      { id: 4, label: 'Node 4' },
      { id: 5, label: 'Node 5' }
    ]);

    const edges = new DataSet<any>([
      { from: 1, to: 3 },
      { from: 1, to: 2 },
      { from: 2, to: 4 },
      { from: 2, to: 5 }
    ]);
    const data = { nodes, edges };
    var options = {
      interaction: { hover: true }
    };
    var network = new Network(container, data, options);
    this.networkInstance = network;
    this.networkInstance.on("click", function (this: VuePrincipaleComponent, params) {
     this.openView()
    })
  }


}
```

If anyone has an explanation for me or a working code to do what I explained, I'll be very happy.

Good evening to all

Comment: this.networkInstance.on("click", function (this: VuePrincipaleComponent, params) {
     this.openView() should be this.networkInstance.on("click",  (this: VuePrincipaleComponent, params) => {
     this.openView()

Comment: @MikeOne thank you ! But it does not compile anyway cause of "An arrow function cannot have a 'this' parameter."

Comment: That payload will never work.. just remove it completely..

Comment: ‘click’, () => { this.openView() } should be enough

Comment: @MikeOne ok thank you so much ! i spent so much time trying to make this work and you unlocked me in 2 min, thanks a lot

Comment: Excellent! Happy coding!